# Get names of cities of customers who have placed an order through employees who have sold

Tags: sql, mariadb

For my CIS class, I have SQL project, I'm still very new to SQL and trying to learn it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Query: Get names of cities of customers who have placed an order through employees who have sold the book "Quickbooks for Business". Required: you must complete this query with sub select.

This is what I tried and giving me an error:

```
SELECT city
FROM zipcode, book, customer, orderline
where city in (SELECT city FROM zipcode WHERE
zip in (SELECT zip 
        FROM customer 
        WHERE cno IN
             (SELECT cno 
              FROM salesorder 
              WHERE ono IN (SELECT ono 
                            FROM orderline 
                            WHERE bno IN (SELECT bno 
                                          FROM book 
                                          WHERE bname ('Quickbooks for Business') )
                            )
              )
        )
```

The error I'm getting is: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 11

Table: [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyAFl.jpg)

Database codes:

```
create table zipcode (
  zip   integer(5) primary key,
  city  varchar(30),
  State varchar(20));

create table employee (
  eno       varchar(10) primary key,
  ename     varchar(30),
  zip       integer(5) references zipcode(zip),
  hire_date date);

create table book (
  bno       integer(5) primary key,
  bname     varchar(30),
  qoh       integer(5) not null,
  price     dec(6,2) not null);

create table customer (
  cno       integer(5) primary key,
  cname     varchar(30),
  street    varchar(30),
  zip       integer(5)  references zipcode(zip),
  phone     char(12));

create table salesOrder (
  ono       integer(5)  primary key,
  cno       integer(5)  references customer(cno),
  eno       varchar(10)  references employees(Eno),
  received  date,
  shipped   date
);

create table orderLine (
  ono       integer(5)  references salesOrder(ono),
  bno       integer(5)  references book(bno),
  quantity  integer(10) not null,
  primary key (ono, bno));
```

Sample data:

```
insert into zipcode values (98225, 'Bellingham', 'WA');
insert into zipcode values (95388, 'Winton', 'CA');
insert into zipcode values (44242, 'Stow', 'OH');
insert into zipcode values (61536, 'Hanna city', 'IL');
insert into zipcode values (01254, 'Richmond', 'MA');
insert into zipcode values (95124, 'San Jose', 'CA');
insert into zipcode values (95382, 'Turlock', 'CA');
insert into zipcode values (95380, 'Turlock', 'CA');
insert into zipcode values (98102, 'Seattle', 'WA');



insert into employee values ('P0239401', 'Jones Hoffer',98225, '2000-12-12');
insert into employee values ('P0239402', 'Jeffrey Prescott',95388, '2016-11-07');
insert into employee values ('P0239403', 'Fred NcFaddeb',95124, '2008-09-01');
insert into employee values ('P0239404', 'Karen Ives',98102, '2014-05-21');


insert into book values (10501, 'Forensic Accounting',200, 229.99);
insert into book values (10502, 'SAP Business One',159, 149.99);
insert into book values (10503, 'Fraud Cases',190, 179.99);
insert into book values (10504, 'CPA Review',65, 279.99);
insert into book values (10605, 'Quickbooks for Business',322, 59.99);
insert into book values (10704, 'Financial Accounting',129, 164.99);
insert into book values (10879, 'Managerial Accounting',155, 114.99);
insert into book values (10933, 'Cost Accounting',122, 219.99);
insert into book values (10948, 'Intermediate Accounting',123, 164.99);
insert into book values (10965, 'Accounting Information Systems',211, 259.99);
insert into book values (10988, 'XBRL in Nutshell',124, 109.99);


insert into customer values (23511, 'Michelle Kuan', '123 Main St.',98225, '360-636-5555');
insert into customer values (23512, 'George Myer', '237 Ash Ave.',95124, '312-678-5555');
insert into customer values (23513, 'Richard Gold', '111 Inwood St.',95124, '312-883-7337');
insert into customer values (23514, 'Robert Smith', '54 Gate Dr.',95388, '206-832-1221');
insert into customer values (23515, 'Christopher David', '777 Loto St.',98225, '360-458-9878');
insert into customer values (23516, 'Adam Beethoven', '234 Park Rd.',95380, '209-546-7299');
insert into customer values (23517, 'Ludwig Bach', '5790 Walnut St.',95382, '209-638-2712');
insert into customer values (23518, 'Kathleen Pedersen', '1233 Federal Ave E', 98102, '360-573-7239');


insert into salesOrder values (1020, 23511, 'P0239403', '2018-01-13', '2018-01-15');
insert into salesOrder values (1021, 23513, 'P0239401', '2018-01-13', '2018-01-16');
insert into salesOrder values (1022, 23513, 'P0239402', '2018-01-15', '2018-01-17');
insert into salesOrder values (1023, 23512, 'P0239403', '2018-01-16', '2018-01-18');
insert into salesOrder values (1024, 23511, 'P0239402', '2018-01-18', '2018-01-20');
insert into salesOrder values (1025, 23511, 'P0239403', '2018-01-29', '2017-01-31');
insert into salesOrder values (1026, 23512, 'P0239404', '2018-01-30', '2018-01-31');
insert into salesOrder values (1027, 23512, 'P0239402', '2018-01-30', '2018-01-31');
insert into salesOrder values (1028, 23512, 'P0239404', '2018-01-30', '2018-01-31');
insert into salesOrder (ONO, CNO, ENO, RECEIVED) values (1029, 23513, 'P0239402', '2018-01-31');
insert into salesOrder (ONO, CNO, ENO, RECEIVED) values (1030, 23511, 'P0239401', '2018-01-31');



insert into orderLine values (1020, 10501,7);
insert into orderLine values (1020, 10502,15);
insert into orderLine values (1020, 10504,3);
insert into orderLine values (1020, 10503,6);
insert into orderLine values (1021, 10605,4);
insert into orderLine values (1022, 10605,2);
insert into orderLine values (1022, 10704,4);
insert into orderLine values (1023, 10879,4);
insert into orderLine values (1023, 10988,19);
insert into orderLine values (1024, 10502,7);
insert into orderLine values (1024, 10988,2);
insert into orderLine values (1025, 10502,4);
insert into orderLine values (1025, 10988,3);
insert into orderLine values (1025, 10948,2);
insert into orderLine values (1026, 10965,15);
insert into orderLine values (1026, 10933,5);
insert into orderLine values (1027, 10933,21);
insert into orderLine values (1028, 10933,9);
insert into orderLine values (1028, 10965,11);
insert into orderLine values (1029, 10933,4);
insert into orderLine values (1029, 10965,10);
insert into orderLine values (1029, 10988,3);
insert into orderLine values (1030, 10965,6);
```

Comment: Don't use the antiquated list of table names in the FROM clause notation shown in the question.  Use explicit joins.  The sub-query requirement is modestly pointless — I'm tolerably certain the query can be written without any sub-queries.

Comment: At the moment, there are three answers.  Note that two of the answers list only 'San Jose'; one of the answers lists 'San Jose' and 'Bellingham'.  Do you know which is the correct result?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `JOINS` instead of `Sub-Queries`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Z.city
FROM zipcode Z
JOIN customer C ON C.zip = Z.zip
JOIN salesOrder S ON S.cno = C.cno
JOIN orderLine O ON O.ono = S.ono
JOIN book B ON B.bno = O.bno
WHERE B.bname = 'Quickbooks for Business'
```

Comment: This lists 'San Jose' (twice) as the city with the sample data.  I'm not convinced that's the correct result — and it's mainly because you don't search the `salesOrder` table twice.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Try my Updated answer. Use `DISTINCT` to avoid duplicates.

Comment: The DISTINCT doesn't really help — I wasn't worried about 'San Jose' appearing twice, but I am a little puzzled that 'Bellingham' does not appear.  Your answer is for the query: _Get names of cities of customers who have placed an order for the book "Quickbooks for Business"._  That's a different query.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Is it possible to give some sample data?

Comment: There's sample data underneath the schema for the tables in the question.  I've made that easier to see (harder to miss).  I didn't just invent the results shown in my answer out of thin air, though.

Comment: And have `INDEX(bname)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Although it could be done better with `joins` but this is how you should do via sub-queries.

```
select city from zipcode 
where zip in
(select zip from customer 
    where cno in(
        select cno from salesOrder 
        where ono in (
            select ono from orderLine 
            where bno in (
                SELECT bno FROM book 
                where bname = 'Quickbooks for Business'
                        )
                    )
                )
)
```

Comment: This lists just 'San Jose' as the city with the sample data.  I'm not convinced that's the correct result — and it's mainly because you don't search the `salesOrder` table twice.

Answer (score 0):

It's a sufficiently complex query that I'd solve it using what I call 'Test-Driven Query Design' or TDQD.  Here are two sequences of queries that lead to the same plausible answer — the expected output is not given in the question, which makes it hard to be sure the query has been analyzed accurately.

The requirement is stated as:

- Query: Get names of cities of customers who have placed an order through employees who have sold the book "Quickbooks for Business".
- Required: you must complete this query with sub-select.

It's possible to interpret the 'with sub-select' requirement to mean 'at least one sub-query' or 'only using sub-queries'.  There are two parts to this answer — the first assuming a single sub-query is sufficient, and the second assuming that only sub-queries may be used.

I regard TDQD as a good way of learning how to build big queries from a number of small queries that you have demonstrated work (because you tested the small queries).

## One sub-query is sufficient

#### TDQD Step A1 — Employees who have sold the book 'Quickbooks for Business'

This is a fairly big first step; it can be broken down into smaller queries to build up the output list of employee numbers if you're not familiar with writing queries.

```
SELECT e.eno
  FROM employee AS e
  JOIN salesorder AS o ON o.eno = e.eno
  JOIN orderline AS l ON o.ono = l.ono
  JOIN book AS b ON l.bno = b.bno
 WHERE b.bname = 'Quickbooks for Business';
```

Output:

```
P0239401
P0239402
```

*Simplification:* The query doesn't need to include the `employee` table; the employee numbers are in the `salesOrder` table:

```
SELECT o.eno
  FROM salesorder AS o
  JOIN orderline AS l ON o.ono = l.ono
  JOIN book AS b ON l.bno = b.bno
 WHERE b.bname = 'Quickbooks for Business';
```

This gives the same result.  The change can be propagated through the all the queries.  Note that the second part of the answer (the 'all sub-queries' variant) does not select from the `employee` table at all, either.  That asymmetry should have tipped me off earlier, but I didn't spot it.  And the chances are that if I'd built up this first step in the TDQD sequence with smaller steps, I wouldn't have made the mistake here, either.

#### TDQD Step A2 — Customers who have placed an order from a list of employees

```
SELECT c.cno
  FROM customer AS c
  JOIN salesorder AS o ON c.cno = o.cno
 WHERE o.eno IN
       (SELECT e.eno
          FROM employee AS e
          JOIN salesorder AS o ON o.eno = e.eno
          JOIN orderline AS l ON o.ono = l.ono
          JOIN book AS b ON l.bno = b.bno
         WHERE b.bname = 'Quickbooks for Business'
       );
```

This gives you the mandatory sub-query.

Output:

```
23513
23511
23513
23511
23512
23513
```

This is an intermediate result; there's no need to remove duplicates or order this result.

*Simplification:*

```
SELECT c.cno
  FROM customer AS c
  JOIN salesorder AS o ON c.cno = o.cno
 WHERE o.eno IN
       (SELECT o.eno
          FROM salesorder AS o
          JOIN orderline AS l ON o.ono = l.ono
          JOIN book AS b ON l.bno = b.bno
         WHERE b.bname = 'Quickbooks for Business'
       );
```

#### TDQD Step A3 — Cities of customers who have placed an order from a list of employees

```
SELECT DISTINCT z.city
  FROM customer   AS c
  JOIN salesorder AS o ON c.cno = o.cno
  JOIN zipcode    AS z ON z.zip = c.zip
 WHERE o.eno IN
       (SELECT e.eno
          FROM employee   AS e
          JOIN salesorder AS o ON o.eno = e.eno
          JOIN orderline  AS l ON o.ono = l.ono
          JOIN book       AS b ON l.bno = b.bno
         WHERE b.bname = 'Quickbooks for Business'
       )
 ORDER BY z.city;
```

Output:

```
Bellingham
San Jose
```

*Simplification:*

```
SELECT DISTINCT z.city
  FROM customer AS c
  JOIN salesorder AS o ON c.cno = o.cno
  JOIN zipcode AS z ON z.zip = c.zip
 WHERE o.eno IN
       (SELECT o.eno
          FROM salesorder AS o
          JOIN orderline AS l ON o.ono = l.ono
          JOIN book AS b ON l.bno = b.bno
         WHERE b.bname = 'Quickbooks for Business'
       )
 ORDER BY z.city;
```

#### TDQD Step A4 — Do not use a sub-query

The assignment requires the sub-query, but the real world doesn't.  However, the SalesOrder table has to figure twice in the query, so
it gets aliased to `o1` and `o2`:

-- TDQD Step 4
-- Do not use a sub-query

```
SELECT DISTINCT z.city
  FROM customer   AS c
  JOIN salesorder AS o1 ON c.cno  = o1.cno
  JOIN zipcode    AS z  ON c.zip  = z.zip
  JOIN employee   AS e  ON o1.eno = e.eno
  JOIN salesorder AS o2 ON o2.eno = e.eno
  JOIN orderline  AS l  ON o2.ono = l.ono
  JOIN book       AS b  ON l.bno  = b.bno
 WHERE b.bname = 'Quickbooks for Business'
 ORDER BY z.city;
```

Output:

```
Bellingham
San Jose
```

*Simplification:*

```
SELECT DISTINCT z.city
  FROM customer   AS c
  JOIN salesorder AS o1 ON c.cno  = o1.cno
  JOIN zipcode    AS z  ON z.zip  = c.zip
  JOIN salesorder AS o2 ON o2.eno = o1.eno
  JOIN orderline  AS l  ON o2.ono = l.ono
  JOIN book       AS b  ON l.bno  = b.bno
 WHERE b.bname = 'Quickbooks for Business'
 ORDER BY z.city;
```

## Only sub-queries may be used

If the assumption that a single sub-query is sufficient is wrong and in fact only sub-queries may be used, then an alternative TDQD sequence follows.

#### TDQD Step B1 — Book number of 'Quickbooks for Business' (QfB)

```
SELECT b.bno
  FROM book AS b
 WHERE b.bname = 'Quickbooks for Business';
```

Output:

```
10605
```

#### TDQD Step B2 — Order numbers for orders including QfB

```
SELECT l.ono
  FROM orderline AS l
 WHERE l.bno IN
       (SELECT b.bno
          FROM book AS b
         WHERE b.bname = 'Quickbooks for Business'
       );
```

Output:

```
1021
1022
```

#### TDQD Step B3 — Employee numbers for orders including QfB

```
SELECT DISTINCT o1.eno
  FROM salesorder AS o1
 WHERE o1.ono IN
       (SELECT l.ono
          FROM orderline AS l
         WHERE l.bno IN
               (SELECT b.bno
                  FROM book AS b
                 WHERE b.bname = 'Quickbooks for Business'
               )
       );
```

Output:

```
P0239401
P0239402
```

#### TDQD Step B4 — Customer numbers who placed an orders through employees in list

```
SELECT DISTINCT o2.cno
  FROM salesorder AS o2
 WHERE o2.eno IN
       (SELECT o1.eno
          FROM salesorder AS o1
         WHERE o1.ono IN
               (SELECT l.ono
                  FROM orderline AS l
                 WHERE l.bno IN
                       (SELECT b.bno
                          FROM book AS b
                         WHERE b.bname = 'Quickbooks for Business'
                       )
               )
       );
```

Output:

```
23511
23512
23513
```

#### TDQD Step B5 — Zip codes of customers who placed orders through employees in list

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.zip
  FROM customer AS c
 WHERE c.cno IN
       (SELECT o2.cno
          FROM salesorder AS o2
         WHERE o2.eno IN
               (SELECT o1.eno
                  FROM salesorder AS o1
                 WHERE o1.ono IN
                       (SELECT l.ono
                          FROM orderline AS l
                         WHERE l.bno IN
                               (SELECT b.bno
                                  FROM book AS b
                                 WHERE b.bname = 'Quickbooks for Business'
                               )
                       )
               )
       );
```

Output:

```
95124
98225
```

#### TDQD Step B6 — Cities of customers who placed orders through employees in list

```
SELECT DISTINCT z.city
  FROM zipcode AS z
 WHERE z.zip IN
       (SELECT DISTINCT c.zip
          FROM customer AS c
         WHERE c.cno IN
               (SELECT o2.cno
                  FROM salesorder AS o2
                 WHERE o2.eno IN
                       (SELECT o1.eno
                          FROM salesorder AS o1
                         WHERE o1.ono IN
                               (SELECT l.ono
                                  FROM orderline AS l
                                 WHERE l.bno IN
                                       (SELECT b.bno
                                          FROM book AS b
                                         WHERE b.bname = 'Quickbooks for Business'
                                       )
                               )
                       )
               )
       );
```

Output:

```
Bellingham
San Jose
```

Fortunately, the same output is generated for both final queries.
This lends us some reassurance that the queries are equivalent.